# LateInitializationError: Field 'width' has not been initialized. while testing the flutter app

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, testing

I have written simple test file to do the testing of my splash screen like this:

splash_test.dart

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('splash_test', (WidgetTester tester) async {

    await tester.pumpWidget(Splash());
    await tester.ensureVisible(find.byWidget(Splash()));
    expect(find.byWidget(Assets.icons.icLogo.svg()), findsOneWidget);
    tester.pump(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    expect(find.byWidget(Login()), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Here the code for my Splash screen

```
SizedBox(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
                color: AppColor.bgBlack,
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 14.w),
                child: Assets.icons.icLogo.svg()),
            Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                child: Assets.icons.icSplashBg.svg(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill)),
          ],
        ))
```

But when I run this command `flutter test test/splash_test.dart`

I get error like this

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following LateError was thrown building Splash(dirty):
LateInitializationError: Field 'width' has not been initialized.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Splash Splash:file:///test/splash_test.dart:11:29

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      SizerUtil.width (package:sizer/util.dart)
#1      SizerExt.w (package:sizer/extension.dart:12:36)
#2      Splash._renderMobile (package:fun_services/screens/splash/splash.dart:41:62)
#3      Splash.build (package:fun_services/screens/splash/splash.dart:25:25)
#4      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5038:49)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:15)
#6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:5)
#7      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4950:5)
#8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4944:5)
#9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3953:16)
#10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3676:20)
#11     RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1176:16)
#12     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1153:5)
#13     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1167:7)
#14     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:5)
#15     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2743:19)
#16     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1336:19)
#17     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:381:5)
#18     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1289:15)
#19     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1218:9)
#20     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.pump.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1185:9)
#23     TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:71:41)
#24     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.pump (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1171:27)
#25     WidgetTester.pumpWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:558:22)
#28     TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:71:41)
#29     WidgetTester.pumpWidget (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:555:27)
#30     main.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/yudizlimitedkaranmehta/Flutter/fun_services/test/splash_test.dart:11:18)
#31     testWidgets.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:171:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided 5 frames from dart:async and package:stack_trace)

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure was thrown running a test:
Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
  Actual: _WidgetFinder:<zero widgets with the given widget (SvgPicture) (ignoring offstage
widgets)>
   Which: means none were found but one was expected

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#4      main.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/yudizlimitedkaranmehta/Flutter/fun_services/test/splash_test.dart:12:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided one frame from package:stack_trace)

This was caught by the test expectation on the following line:
  file:///Users/yudizlimitedkaranmehta/Flutter/fun_services/test/splash_test.dart line 12
The test description was:
  splash_test
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following message was thrown:
Multiple exceptions (2) were detected during the running of the current test, and at least one was
unexpected.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
00:01 +0 -1: splash_test [E]                                                                                                                     
  Test failed. See exception logs above.
  The test description was: splash_test
```

So can anyone help me with this? I'm using [Sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer) library and it gives error for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your widgets with `MaterialApp` and then with `Sizer` for testing:

```
return Sizer(
  builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Splash(),
    );
  },
);
```